odbc_prepare(): SQLColAttribute can't handle SQL_DESC_OCTET_LENGTH: [S1C00] [TimesTen][TimesTen 18.1.4.42.0 CLIENT]Driver not capable
Here is my connection.php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dsn = 'DSN=demo;Server=demo;UID=demo;PWD=demo';

$conn = odbc_connect($dsn, '', '');

if ($conn) {
    // Connection successful, proceed with query execution
    echo "Connection successful.<br>";

    // Define the SQL query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";  // Ensure this is the correct table name

    // Prepare and execute the SQL query
    $stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
    if (odbc_execute($stmt)) {
        // Get column names
        $columns = [];
        $num_fields = odbc_num_fields($stmt);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_fields; $i++) {
            $columns[] = odbc_field_name($stmt, $i);
        }

        // Print the column names
        print_r($columns);
        echo "<br>";

        // Fetch and display the results row by row
        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($stmt)) {

            print_r($row);
            echo "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Query execution failed: " . odbc_errormsg($conn);
    }

    // Close the connection
    odbc_close($conn);
} else {
    echo "Connection failed: " . odbc_errormsg();
}
?>

from the localhost i cannot find the column name everytime it's ouput like
Warning: odbc_prepare(): SQLColAttribute can't handle SQL_DESC_OCTET_LENGTH: \[S1C00\] \[TimesTen\]\[TimesTen 18.1.4.42.0 CLIENT\]Driver not capable in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\timesten\\test_connection.php on line 20

Warning: odbc_prepare(): SQLColAttribute can't handle SQL_DESC_OCTET_LENGTH: \[S1C00\] \[TimesTen\]\[TimesTen 18.1.4.42.0 CLIENT\]Driver not capable in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\timesten\\test_connection.php on line 20

Warning: odbc_prepare(): SQLColAttribute can't handle SQL_DESC_OCTET_LENGTH: \[S1C00\] \[TimesTen\]\[TimesTen 18.1.4.42.0 CLIENT\]Driver not capable in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\timesten\\test_connection.php on line 20
Array ( \[0\] =\> \[1\] =\>  \[2\] =\>  )
Array ( \[John Doe\] =\> John Doe \[\] =\> 30 \[\] =\> john.doe@example.com )
Array ( \[Jane Smith\] =\> Jane Smith \[\] =\> 25 \[\] =\> jane.smith@example.com )
Array ( \[Alice Johnson\] =\> Alice Johnson \[\] =\> 28 \[\] =\> alice.johnson@example.com )
Array ( \[Bob Brown\] =\> Bob Brown \[\] =\> 35 \[\] =\> bob.brown@example.com )
Array ( \[Charlie Davis\] =\> Charlie Davis \[\] =\> 40 \[\] =\> charlie.davis@example.com )

i want to see the column name . it always showing me like this "Warning: odbc_prepare(): SQLColAttribute can't handle SQL_DESC_OCTET_LENGTH: [S1C00] [TimesTen][TimesTen 18.1.4.42.0 CLIENT]Driver not capable in C:\xampp\htdocs\timesten\connection.php on line 20"

Instead of using odbc_prepare and odbc_execute, you can use the odbc_exec function, which might be more compatible with your driver.
$result = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
if ($result) {
    // Get column names
    $columns = [];
    $num_fields = odbc_num_fields($result);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_fields; $i++) {
        $columns[] = odbc_field_name($result, $i);
    }

    // Print the column names
    print_r($columns);
    echo "<br>";

    // Fetch and display the results row by row
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
        print_r($row);
        echo "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Query execution failed: " . odbc_errormsg($conn);
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
